# Posting a link with image and text to Facebook wall

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to replicate the functionality to share a story on a Facebook wall similar to what this [site](http://www.nj.com/mercer/index.ssf/2011/05/princeton_rider_baseball_finis.html) has.

When you click on the share it should ask you to authenticate to facebook, if you are already authenticated it should show you the story to post to facebook.

I got the authentication part to work using the [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) . I am not sure how to show the content to post to the wall.

Could anyone please provide an example.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking abou the "share" button under the twitter button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
# We require the library
require("facebook.php");

# Creating the facebook object
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
    'cookie' => true
));

# Let's see if we have an active session
$session = $facebook->getSession();

if(!empty($session)) {
    # Active session, let's try getting the user id (getUser()) and user info (api->('/me'))
    try{
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();

        # let's check if the user has granted access to posting in the wall
        $api_call = array(
            'method' => 'users.hasAppPermission',
            'uid' => $uid,
            'ext_perm' => 'publish_stream'
        );
        $can_post = $facebook->api($api_call);
        if($can_post){
            # post it!
            # $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/feed', 'post', array('message' => 'Saying hello from my Facebook app!'));

            # using all the arguments
            $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/feed', 'post', array(
                'message' => 'The message',
                'name' => 'The name',
                'description' => 'The description',
                'caption' => 'The caption',
                'picture' => 'http://i.imgur.com/yx3q2.png',
                'link' => 'http://net.tutsplus.com/'
            ));
            echo 'Posted!';
        } else {
            die('Permissions required!');
        }
    } catch (Exception $e){}
} else {
    # There's no active session, let's generate one
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    header("Location: ".$login_url);
}
?>
```